# Passing string to JavaScript in iOS Can't get the function Called

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

Spent a whole evening googling this and still no dice.
I'm just trying to pass a string to an embedded html/javascript test file. I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the function called either :[

Heres what i got code wise:

DetailedController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    UIWebView *webView;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Detailinfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *DetailName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dob;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;


@end
```

DetailedController.m

```
#import "DetailController.h"

@interface DetailController ()


@end

@implementation DetailController
@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    UINavigationItem *topBar;
    topBar.title = self.Detailinfo[0];
    self.DetailName.text = self.Detailinfo[0];
    self.dob.text = self.Detailinfo[1];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"javascriptTest" ofType:@"html"]];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadText(%@)", self.Detailinfo[1]]];

}





@end
```

and the HTML file javascriptTest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test JavaScript</title>
<script>
function loadText(txtString)
{
    var divd = document.createElement('div');
    divd.innerHTML = "<p>" + txtString + "</p>";
    document.body.appendChild(divd);
    document.getElementById('info').value = "";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    loaded
<!--
<input type="text" id="info" />
<button onclick="loadText(document.getElementById('info').value)"> Load Text </button> 
-->
</body>
</html>
```

any help is much appreciated :]

UPDATE
As @ACB said, just needed to add '' inside the javascript function `@"loadText('%@')"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@"loadText('%@')"`

Comment: @ACB is right. And you may need to escape the string just in case it has any " character inside. There's no short of questions to help you do that actually ;)

Comment: @ACB the '' where what did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change,

```
@"loadText(%@)"
```

to

```
@"loadText('%@')"
```

Since you are passing a string on to this javascript function, it should be inside quotes.

As Fabio said, you might have to escape the string if it has any `"` inside it.